# Why my (text) scene is so small when integrating it in the vse?

Tags: text-object, scene

I have little experience with blender, i am using version 3.4.1.

I'm just trying to create some titles for my clips. So, the camera view is this:

[image: Camera view from my scene]

But when I add this scene to the main timeline, it shows like this:

[image: Timeline view]

and, it's the same whether I resize the text in the scene, move it around or even get it out of focus from the selected camera. So it seems the scene is not reflected in the main view as it should.

Any help with this?

Comment: I can't really comment on your immediate problem but version 3.6 isn't even in beta yet and 3.5 hasn't been released so why are you using such a new version if you've not used Blender much? 3.6 may well have unresolved bugs in it so I'd stick to the current 3.4.1 or 3.5 release for the moment.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I am using version 3.4.1.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe someone else here has experience with the VSE and can answer your problem.